# GitHub activity feed does not display all entries

Tags: github, github-issues

I'm wondering why some activities are not displayed in my feed. The doc says:

> The feed shows you events from people you follow and repositories you
>   watch.

Just yesterday, a colleague of mine committed and pushed something to a repo I'm watching but I cannot see this activity in my feed.

Why does it happen? Do I have to manage some settings somewhere?